# Working remotely in the US on an M2 visa

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas

An M-2 visa is a US visa for spouses or children of someone on an M-1 visa, which is a type of student visa.

If I am on an M-2 visa, is it possible to work while in the US for a company based in my home country, for clients in my home country?

I won’t be working for a US company. My current employer would continue to employ me.

If this is not possible, is there a specific working visa for a non-US based company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are not authorized to work while in the US in M-2 status. It doesn't make a difference that you are working remotely and that the company is outside the US -- you would still be physically in the US, and performing work.

No, there is no general visa type for working for a foreign company while in the US.